# How to obtain the 'figure' of a 'control' added with 'javacomponent' routine

Tags: java, matlab, user-interface

**Background**

When displaying a `msgbox` after clicking some button in a Matlab GUI, the dialog always *magically* appears on top of the figure that holds the clicked button ... and this whatever the position of the figure and even if no reference to this figure is passed to the `msgbox` call.

Well, looking at the code for `msgbox`, this not just *magic*. Indeed in the code there is a call to [`gcbo`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcbo.html) which returns the control whose callback is executing and the figure containing this control (via a call to [`ancestor`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ancestor.html) of type *figure*).

**Problem**

The `gcbo` mechanism works well as long as controls are added with `uicontrol` routine, when custom controls are added with `javacomponent` routine, `gcbo` mechanism fails to find the figure and the `msgbox` is displayed in the middle of the screen instead of on top of the figure as shown in the code below:

```
function [] = gcboDemo()
%[  
    % Create figure
    fig = figure('Name', 'Hello', 'units', 'normalized', 'Position', [1/5, 0.5, 1/5, 1/5]);

    % Add standard matlab button
    matlabBtn = uicontrol('Parent', fig, 'units', 'normalized', 'Position', [1/5, 0.5, 1/5, 1/5], 'String', 'Matlab');
    set(matlabBtn, 'Callback', @(sender, args)onBtnClicked())

    % Add java button
    [javaBtn, jContainer] = javacomponent('javax.swing.JButton', [0 0 1 1], fig); 
    set(jContainer, 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [3/5, 0.5, 1/5, 1/5]);
    javaBtn.setText('Java');
    set(javaBtn, 'ActionPerformedCallback', @(sender, args)onBtnClicked())
%]
end
function [] = onBtnClicked()
%[
    % This is what 'msgbox' is doing to find nice position for where to draw on screen
    % 1) It looks for control intiating the callback and the figure containing it
    % 2) It changes 'msgbox' position so it will appear over the figure
    % NB: If no figure is found, 'msgbox' appear in middle of the screen 
    [controlOriginatingCallback, figureContainingObjectOriginatingCallback] = gcbo(); 

    if (~isempty(figureContainingObjectOriginatingCallback))
        msg = sprintf('Control = `%s` in Figure = `%s`', class(controlOriginatingCallback), get(figureContainingObjectOriginatingCallback, 'Name'));
    else
        msg = sprintf('Control = `%s` in Figure = `???`', class(controlOriginatingCallback));
    end

    uiwait(msgbox(msg, 'modal'));
%]
end
```

**Question**

I like the behavior of `gcbo` and would like to reproduce it for controls I add with `javacomponent` (not just only for `msgbox` but also for custom dialogs I may create myself).

Is there a simple way I can get back the reference to the `figure` that holds controls added with `javacomponent` ?

NB1: Currently I can get the object whose callback is executing via `ctrl = get(0, 'CallbackObject')` and I can go up to the figure via `ctrl.getParent()` but returned reference is the java object and I don't know how to obtain peer reference in Matlab world.

NB2: I know I can use `[jControl, hContainer] = javacomponent(...)` syntax and pass `hContainer` to the callback iin order to track reference to the containing `figure` but would prefer to keep similar mechanism as `gcbo` (for instance to override implementation of `gcbo` and have all routines using it to work even with `javacomponent` objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tries I found a solution:

- I get the figure as a java handle with `thisFigure = get(control, 'TopLevelAncestor')`
- I temporarly modify the `Name` property of maltab figures handles one-by-one until `thisfigure.getTitle()` matches with the temporary name I set.

NB: Would have been better to change java-side `Title` and find matlab-side `Name` with `findobj` but changing java-side does not update matlab-side (while the reverse works, so ...)

Here is the code for [`gcbo`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcbo.html) override:

```
%
% PURPOSE:
%
%    Gets handle to current callback control and 
%    handle to the figure containing that control. 
%
% SYNTAX:
%
%    [control] = gcboex();
%    [control, fig] = gcboex();
%
% DESCRIPTION:
%
%    Works exactly the same way as native `gcbo` routine except
%    that it is also working for controls created with `javacomponent`.
% 

%% ---
function [control, fig] = gcboex()
%[
    % Obtain graphical element whose callback is executing
    control = get(0, 'CallbackObject');

    % Case not executing from callback on a graphical element
    if (isempty(control) || ~(ishghandle(control) || ishandle(control)))
        control = [];
        fig = [];
        return;
    end

    % Obtain the figure containing the graphical element
    if (isempty(strfind(class(control), 'javahandle_withcallbacks')))

        fig = ancestor(control, 'figure'); % Do the same as native `gcbo` routine

    else
        try

            % Obtain the containing figure as a java handle
            thisFigure = get(control, 'TopLevelAncestor');
            if (isempty(strfind(class(thisFigure), 'FigureFrameProxy'))), error('Not inside a figure'); end

            % Obtain all figures as matlab handles
            allFigures = findobj(0, 'Type', 'figure');

            % Temporarly modify figure names one by one and check
            % from the java side that this our title that has changed
            %
            % NB: Would be easier to do modify java-side title or ToolTipString
            % and use 'findobj' but when we modify java-side the changes are not
            % reported on matlab side even with forceGuiUpdate, so we do the reverse (which is working) ...
            fig = []; 
            searchedName = char(java.util.UUID.randomUUID);
            for fi = 1:length(allFigures)
                currentFig = allFigures(fi);
                oldName = get(currentFig, 'Name');
                set(currentFig, 'Name', searchedName); forceGuiUpdate();
                if (strfind(char(thisFigure.getTitle()), searchedName))
                    fig = currentFig; 
                end
                set(currentFig, 'Name', oldName); forceGuiUpdate();
                if (~isempty(fig)), break; end
            end

        catch
            fig = [];
        end        
    end
%]
end
function [] = forceGuiUpdate()
%[
    try
        drawnow nocallbacks; 
    catch
        drawnow; % Force update (not sure 'nocallbacks' option was introduced very recently ...) 
    end
%]
end
```

Here is full sample code with `gcboex` patch:

```
function [] = gcboDemo()
%[  
    % Create figure
    fig = figure('Name', 'Hello', 'units', 'normalized', 'Position', [1/5, 0.5, 1/5, 1/5]);

    % Add check box
    cb =uicontrol('Parent', fig, 'Style', 'Checkbox', 'units', 'normalized', 'Position', [1/5, 4/5, 1/3, 1/5], 'String', 'Use modified gcbo');

    % Add standard matlab button
    matlabBtn = uicontrol('Parent', fig, 'units', 'normalized', 'Position', [1/5, 0.5, 1/5, 1/5], 'String', 'Matlab');
    set(matlabBtn, 'Callback', @(sender, args)onBtnClicked(cb))

    % Add java button
    [javaBtn, jContainer] = javacomponent('javax.swing.JButton', [0 0 1 1], fig); 
    set(jContainer, 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [3/5, 0.5, 1/5, 1/5]);
    set(jContainer, 'Tag', char(java.util.UUID.randomUUID));
    javaBtn.setText('Java');
    set(javaBtn, 'ActionPerformedCallback', @(sender, args)onBtnClicked(cb))
%]
end
function [] = onBtnClicked(cb)
%[
    % Check if using 'gcboex'
    useGcboex = (get(cb, 'Value') ~= 0);

    if (useGcboex)
        [controlOriginatingCallback, figureContainingObjectOriginatingCallback] = gcboex();
    else
        [controlOriginatingCallback, figureContainingObjectOriginatingCallback] = gcbo();
    end

    if (~isempty(figureContainingObjectOriginatingCallback))
        msg = sprintf('Control = `%s` in Figure = `%s`', class(controlOriginatingCallback), get(figureContainingObjectOriginatingCallback, 'Name'));
    else
        msg = sprintf('Control = `%s` in Figure = `???`', class(controlOriginatingCallback));
    end

    b = msgbox(msg, 'modal');
    if (useGcboex)
        moveguiex(b, 'Over', figureContainingObjectOriginatingCallback);
    end
    uiwait(b);
%]
end

%% ----
function [control, fig] = gcboex()
%[
    % Obtain graphical element whose callback is executing
    control = get(0, 'CallbackObject');

    % Case not executing from callback on a graphical element
    if (isempty(control) || ~(ishghandle(control) || ishandle(control)))
        control = [];
        fig = [];
        return;
    end

    % Obtain the figure containing the graphical element
    if (isempty(strfind(class(control), 'javahandle_withcallbacks')))

        fig = ancestor(control, 'figure'); % Do the same as native `gcbo` routine

    else
        try

            % Obtain the containing figure as a java handle
            thisFigure = get(control, 'TopLevelAncestor');
            if (isempty(strfind(class(thisFigure), 'FigureFrameProxy'))), error('Not inside a figure'); end

            % Obtain all figures as matlab handles
            allFigures = findobj(0, 'Type', 'figure');

            % Temporarly modify figure names one by one and check
            % from the java side that this our title that has changed
            %
            % NB: Would be easier to do modify java-side title or ToolTipString
            % and use 'findobj' but when we modify java-side the changes are not
            % reported on matlab side even with forceGuiUpdate, so we do the reverse (which is working) ...
            fig = []; 
            searchedName = char(java.util.UUID.randomUUID);
            for fi = 1:length(allFigures)
                currentFig = allFigures(fi);
                oldName = get(currentFig, 'Name');
                set(currentFig, 'Name', searchedName); forceGuiUpdate();
                if (strfind(char(thisFigure.getTitle()), searchedName))
                    fig = currentFig; 
                end
                set(currentFig, 'Name', oldName); forceGuiUpdate();
                if (~isempty(fig)), break; end
            end

        catch
            fig = [];
        end        
    end
%]
end
function [] = forceGuiUpdate()
%[
    try
        drawnow nocallbacks; 
    catch
        drawnow; % Force update (not sure 'nocallbacks' option was introduced very recently ...) 
    end
%]
end

%% ---
function [] = moveguiex(h, positionDescription, varargin)
%[
    % Check arguments
    if (nargin < 2), error('Not enough input arguments.'); end
    if (~ischar(positionDescription)), error('Invalid position identifier.'); end
    if (~ishandle(h)), error('Invalid graphic handle.'); end

    % 'CenterOf'
    if (strcmpi(strtrim(positionDescription), 'CenterOf') || ...
        strcmpi(strtrim(positionDescription), 'Over'))

        % Additional checks
        if (nargin < 3), error('Not enough input arguments.'); end
        if (nargin ~= 3), error('Too many input arguments.'); end
        p = varargin{1}; if (~ishandle(p)), error('Invalid graphic handle.'); end

        % Work
        if (isempty(p))
            pp = get(0,'screensize'); pl = pp(1); pb = pp(2); pw = pp(3); ph = pp(4); 
        else
            pp = getpixelposition(p); pl = pp(1); pb = pp(2); pw = pp(3); ph = pp(4); 
        end
        tp = getpixelposition(h); tw = tp(3); th = tp(4);

        switch(lower(strtrim(positionDescription)))
            case 'centerof',
                tl = pl + (1/2)*(pw - tw);
                tb = pb + (1/2)*(ph - th);
            case 'over',
                tl = pl + (1/2)*(pw - tw);
                tb = pb + (2/3)*(ph - th);
            otherwise,
                error('Out of range');
        end
        setpixelposition(h, [tl tb tw th]);

        % End
        return;

    end

    % Oops
    error('Position = `%s` is not supported', positionDescription);
%]
end
```